In Bleach, where did Nel's name come from?
If the Espadas were named after the architects (or Architecture Designers) just like this link says so, does that mean that Neliel Tu Odelschwanck is named after an architect too? If so, then who is Nel named after?
Does anyone have any idea where Nelliel's name originated from?
